# Nullpointexception - setImageBitmap

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I have unexpectedly received a nullpoint exception error that I have been trying to resolve but have been unsuccesful. I have included the logcat below.

```
09-28 20:12:29.543: E/AndroidRuntime(3588):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-28 20:26:37.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3778): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 20:26:37.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3778): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dooba.beta/com.dooba.beta.MoodActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 20:26:37.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-28 20:26:37.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-28 20:26:37.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-28 20:26:37.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-28 20:26:37.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-28 20:26:37.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-28 20:26:37.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-28 20:26:37.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 20:26:37.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-28 20:26:37.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-28 20:26:37.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-28 20:26:37.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-28 20:26:37.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3778): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 20:26:37.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at com.dooba.beta.MoodActivity.onCreate(MoodActivity.java:60)
09-28 20:26:37.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-28 20:26:37.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-28 20:26:37.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3778):     ... 11 more
```

Below is the activity code:

```
public class MoodActivity extends Activity {

private FeedbackDialog feedBack;
private LocationManager mlocManager; 
private LocationListener mlocListener; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mood);
    ImageView ishowsshadow = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.ishows);
    ishowsshadow.setImageBitmap(highlightImage(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.band5)));



      ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

         // inform the Parse Cloud that it is ready for notifications
         PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, matchOptionActivity.class, R.drawable.ic_dooba);
            ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
            PushService.subscribe(this, "Updates", LoginActivity.class, R.drawable.ic_dooba);

    feedBack = new FeedbackDialog(this, "AF-46D8F2A319EA-0A");
    mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();



  if(mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
  {
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1800000, 0, mlocListener);
  }
  else
  {

      Context context = getApplicationContext();

      AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      builder1.setMessage("Your network provider is disabled. We need access to your location as it will help us provide you with the best recommendations. " +
            "We determine your location based on availability of cell tower and WiFi access points. Hence, please configure your network.");
      builder1.setCancelable(true);
      builder1.setPositiveButton("View Settings",
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
              dialog.cancel();

              startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

          }
      });

      AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
      alert11.setCancelable(false); 
      alert11.show();


  }




public Bitmap highlightImage(Bitmap src) {
      // create new bitmap, which will be painted and becomes result image
      Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth() + 96, src.getHeight() + 96, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
      // setup canvas for painting
      Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOut);
      // setup default color
      canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
      // create a blur paint for capturing alpha
      Paint ptBlur = new Paint();
      ptBlur.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(15, Blur.NORMAL));
      int[] offsetXY = new int[2];
      // capture alpha into a bitmap
      Bitmap bmAlpha = src.extractAlpha(ptBlur, offsetXY);
      // create a color paint
      Paint ptAlphaColor = new Paint();
      ptAlphaColor.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
      // paint color for captured alpha region (bitmap)
      canvas.drawBitmap(bmAlpha, offsetXY[0], offsetXY[1], ptAlphaColor);
      // free memory
      bmAlpha.recycle();

      // paint the image source
      canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

      // return out final image
      return bmOut;
     }
```

Line 60 where I believe the error is located right under onCreate:

```
ishowsshadow.setImageBitmap(highlightImage(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.band5)));
```

below is the portion of the layout that reference the imageview

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ishows"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/icasual"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/experience_eating"
        android:src="@drawable/band5"
        />
```

Comment: What does the getResources() return ?

Comment: What is the result of your debugging tries? You've tried to debug that program to find what exactly is null, right? And if you tried it and couldn't find the right spot, when split your line 60 into smaller parts. It does certainly too much for a single line.

Comment: Is your `ImageView` is in `activity_mood.xml` file?

Answer (score 0):

try to add options in source decoding and modify

`getResources()` in `context.getResources()`

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
```

Comment: He is getting `Null Pointer Exception` not `Out of Memory`.